# Can any real continuous function defined on compact manifold can be approximated by smooth function when restricted on charts?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

As the title suggests, if $f\in C(M;\mathbb{R})$ where $M$ is compact topological manifold. Can $f$ be approximated by smooth functions when restricted on charts?, i.e. for atlas $(U_{i},\psi_{i})$, $fo\psi^{-1}_{i}|_{U_{i}}$ can be approximated by smooth functions on $\psi^{-1}_{i}(U_{i})$.

**Edit**
The approximation is in the sense that there exist $f_{i}\in C^{\infty}(\psi_{i}^{-1}(U_{i});\mathbb{R})$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} \sup|f_{i}-f|=0$.

Comment: Approximated in which topology?

Comment: In the supremum norm

Comment: I think that you can approximate $f$ as a whole...

Comment: So even $M$ do not have a smooth structure, there still exist $C^{\infty}(M)$ which is dense?

Comment: Yup, I might write an answer later

Comment: A chart is just an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. So you're asking whether any continuous function on an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ can be approximated by a smooth one. There are many ways to do this. If you restrict to compactly supported functions, then fix a smooth function $\chi$ supported on a neighborhood of $0$ and, for each $t > 0$, denote $\chi_t(x) = t^{-n}\chi(t^{-1}x)$. Then given any compactly supported function $f$ on $U$, the convolution of $f$ and $\chi_t$, with $t$ sufficiently small, is smooth also compactly supprted on $U$, and $f_t$ converges uniformly to $f$.